# i have got error reading dynamic string at the following code:

Tags: c

i have got error string reading at following code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    main()

{
 int i = 0, j = 0,count=0;

 char x,*str3;

 char str2[50] = "nadir beton12345!";

for (; x = str2[i] = str2[j]; j++)
 {
    if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z' || x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')
    {
        count++;

        i++;
    }
}

        str3 = (char *)malloc((count * sizeof(char))+1);

        printf("the new str without spaces and numbers is: \"%s\"\n", str3);

        free(str3);
}
```

i debug the program and when the debugger arrive to the dynamic allocation it cant read the string.

thanks.

Comment: Well, it makes sense, you are never actually str3 so it contains garbage

Comment: Please try to fix the indentation of your code (tabs may not be displayed correctly on Stack Overflow, so consider using spaces). By making your code more readable, users have a greater chance to contribute to your question to help you solve your problem.

Comment: If you do an in-place modification, why do you allocate space for a new string?

Comment: Try including stdlib.h. I'm pretty sure malloc is a standard library function.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not with the malloc, but with the assignment:

```
char str2[50] = "nadir beton12345!";
```

This creates a constant string located in a read-only segment of the process virtual memory. So this

```
str2[i] = str2[j]
```

cannot be done.

You should allocate str3 before the loop and update str3 as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

main()

{
   int i = 0, j = 0,count=0;

   char x,*str3;

   char str2[50] = "nadir beton12345!";

   str3 = (char *)malloc((count * sizeof(char))+1);

   for (; (x = str3[i] = str2[j]) != '\0'; j++)
   {
      if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z' || x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')
      {
        count++;

        i++;
      }
   }

   printf("the new str without spaces and numbers is: \"%s\"\n", str3);

   free(str3);
}
```

Hope I helped,

Comment: No, that string is perfectly modifiable.  You might be thinking of `const char* foo = "asdf";`.  Modifying those bytes is likely to be a problem.